# SameSite None cookie not sent with cross origin IFrame request

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe, cross-domain, samesite

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on domain `a.com` and this application is sending an IFrame request to `b.com` which is a Web API. When I debug this in the local machine (when the application and the API are running on `localhost`), this IFrame call works fine. But then, when these are deployed to the server, the application and API are on different domains and the IFrame call does not work anymore.

I have identified that the cookies are not sent along with the cross-origin IFrame request. So, I set the cookie properties to `SameSite=None` and `Secure=True`. Still, the cookies are not being sent with the request. How can I debug this further?

I am using google chrome version `87.0.4280.141`.

See the cookies here:

[image: Cookies]

See the request headers here:

[image]

Comment: Since the iframe loads in the browser, the origin of the request will not be a.com but the client browser. Now a request to b.com will be sent via the browser, it is my understanding that cookies set by b.com can and will be resent to b.com by the browser but cookies sent from a.com will not be sent to b.com only because the page containing the iframe was on a.com.

Comment: @Hamed Should I be setting cookies in the browser from `b.com`?

Comment: I believe so. If the iframe connects to b.com it can only send back cookies originally sent from b.com. Although at this point you need to reason about the SameSite policy as well. I am not sure which browsers still support "none"+"secure" policy.